# Font Awesome Icon Not Showing In Selectbox

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am creating a front end project but my icons has not been displayed in UI. I tried &#xf0ac code and set my select font-family to 'Font Awesome 5', however, it has not been displayed again.

```css
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome 5 Free', 'sans-serif';
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome 5 Free";
  src: url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="public">Hi, &#xf0ac;</option>
</select>
```

I also tried 'FontAwesome' instead of 'FontAwesome 5 Free'. It didn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that the `eot` font format is only supported by Internet Explorer?

You should probably embed the `woff`/`woff2` version.

As soon as I change `eof` to `woff` or `woff2` in the CDN URL you are loading the font from, it works fine in my Chromium-based browser - https://jsfiddle.net/bwj04qr2/

```css
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome 5 Free', 'sans-serif';
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome 5 Free";
  src: url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0");
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="public">Hi, &#xf0ac;</option>
</select>
```